# Laravel SELECT INTO OUTFILE: writing to file error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, slash

I am trying to backup my database using the `select into outfile` statement in the Laravel 4.
this is my code

```
$file = storage_path('db.sql');
DB::statement("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".$file."' FROM profiles");
```

But I receive the following error:

```
..Can not create/write to ..laravelappstorage\db.sql
```

Actually it strips the slashes in the file path,

what is the solution?

Comment: I think you should double the slashes inside the string, and review the webserver user permissions in that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ademir Nuno mentioned I need to double the slashes

```
DB::statement("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".addslashes($file)."' FROM profiles");
```

and have user permissions