# PHP - Exporting database records directly into CSV file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export a dataset of rows into a csv/txt file with a single query as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248506/laravel-select-into-outfile-writing-to-file-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-can-i-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format/1497377#1497377), by executing a Laravel PHP script on a WSL environment with no root user.

The issues I found are the same as mentioned in those posts, but I can't get my mind into solving it.

When first executing a similar SQL query into MySQL like:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/posts.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" FROM posts;
```

I receive

> Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '\tmp\posts.csv' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Whatever the directory is (I've tried with plenty of them) except for the MySQL default directory, which  I won't have access to once deployed.

The file exists and is empty, so I guess it's the same permissions issue, so far I check:

- `show grants` shows `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` which returns null
- `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` (As a test) and results are the same, no changes.
- I tried executing the PHP script with `root` user, same results.

Any ideas what is missing or what steps are to be done?

Comment: Either `'/tmp/'` directory not exists or it is not accessible for an account which is used for MySQL server running. Also check does your MySQL account have FILE privilege - it must be granted separately. PS. The filename in the query and in the error message differs. ??? *The file exists and is empty* Do you mean that the file which you want the data to be saved into already exists? If so then you must remove it. If not then you'll receive "ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '%s' already exists".

Comment: I granted `FILE` privileges in step 3. And by the file existing I meant I followed MySQL docs that says  `The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot be an existing file` so it seems is the correct way to go (create an empty file for the records to be saved in)

Comment: _"so it seems is the correct way to go (create an empty file for the records to be saved in)"_ - please clarify, are you saying that yourself created this file, _before_ you made the select statement? If so, _"file_name cannot be an existing file"_ explicitly says the file must _not_ exist already.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake in that way, as the file should NOT exist. However I tried after with a non existing file and the results are the same. I lack the permissions. I am checking how to set a specific value to `secure_file_priv` variable and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've added a full local path into `secure_file_priv` variable and the SQL query via MySQL workbench is executing correctly, so that solves that issue!! When trying the same query but via PHP script (I'm in a Windows 10 WSL subsystem) the script fails by warning that the directory is incorrect and I must use the one previously set. I guess it could be because WSL dir isn't being mapped properly